# Exchange 2019 Archive Policy moves items to Recoverable Items Folder

Tags: exchange, archive, exchange-2019

So we have 3 Exchange 2019 servers in our environment. Two of them are DAG servers storing mailboxes, third is archive mailboxes only.

For most users everything works fine, however there are few, where all items marked with archive retention tags are moved to inplace archive mailboxes, but straight to "Recoverable Items" folder (found this by exporting user archive to pst).

What's interesting, if I move archive mailbox to the same database, as mailbox connected to it, everything works fine.

Of course I checked all the retention tags set by user.

Here is how it looks if i use Get-MailboxFolderStatistics

---

**xxx@domain.com\Folder nadrzędny magazynu informacji - 290.1 MB (304,214,249 bytes)** (root folder)

**xxx@domain.com\Recoverable Items - 1.467 GB (1,575,517,001 bytes)**

Tried creating new inplace archive mailbox, repairing, moving to different DB - nothing.

Any ideas, Guys?

---

**Edit: I have found that this problem occurs only when mailbox is on different SERVER than archive**

Answer (score 0):

Whose "**Recoverable Items**" folder did these emails reach to? The primary mailbox or the archive mailbox?

Were emails removed immediately since they were sent(Move to the **`Recoverable Items`** folder)? Or they were saved for one or more days and then be deleted?

If the emails went straight to "**Recoverable Items**", it seems that these items have been **`Delete and Allow Recovery`**(**[Retention actions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/policy-and-compliance/mrm/retention-tags-and-retention-policies?view=exchserver-2019#retention-tags)**). Did you add a retention tag(which is like the following snapshot) in the retention policy which was applied by your mailboxes?

[image]

For further troubleshooting, please provide the retention policy which was applied by your mailboxes and its retention tags by running the following commands and viewing the following interface:

```
Get-Mailbox <MailboxIdentity> | fl RetentionPolicy

Get-RetentionPolicy "<Retention Policy Name>" | fl Id, RetentionPolicyTagLinks
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: ad 1. archive mailbox

ad 2. immediately. It went straight to "Recoverable Items" instead of root folder

ad 3. To make everything clear I've even created new policy with one personal retention tag (15 days move to archive) and set to this user.

[link](https://imgur.com/Up1TSA5)

[link](https://imgur.com/6yXtqLf)

Get-RetentionPolicy "test" | fl Id, RetentionPolicyTagLinks

Id : TEST

RetentionPolicyTagLinks : {Personal 15 day move to archive}

Comment: Did the same issue exist after re-assigning a new retention policy to this mailbox?
What happened if you disable cached exchange mode in Outlook and then receive emails, or close Outlook application and use OWA to receiving emails?

Comment: ad 1. Yes
ad 2. Tried, same thing happens.

Comment: Is it helpful if you run the command "Start-ManagedFolderAssistant"(https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/start-managedfolderassistant?view=exchange-ps) to process messaging records management (MRM) of mailboxes that you specify?

Comment: I use it after every action to see if anything changed :)

Comment: Check if there is any Junk Option making the emails be permanently deleted so that they were moved to the Recoverable folder.